# express js: Conditional route parameters with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I need to match a route that has this form: `/city-state-country`

Where `city` can be in formats: san-francisco (multiword separated by '-') or newtown (single word).

And also some countries have `state` missing, so '-state' param in route should be optional.

How can I strictly match match my route pattern, meaning that it will take either 2 or 3 parameters separated by '-'?

I had something like this:

```
app.get(/([A-Za-z\-\']+)-([A-Za-z\']+)-([A-Za-z\']+)/, routes.index_location);
```

but, it didn't work.

Ultimately, cases like these should not work:

```
/c/san-jose-ca-us
/san-jose-ca-us-someweirdstuff
```

Comment: i'd say let the route be a route, capture the string as a parameter, and then `split('-')` and then verify from there.  You'll probably need a dictionary of states and cities and so on.

Comment: also if you have any control over it, it would make your life much easier if the spaces in the city names were underscores.  Either way this is a non-trivial task.  You should look at the npm lib natural to tokenize the input.

Answer (score 1):

`san-jose-ca-us-someweirdstuff` can be parsed as `san-jose-ca` (city) - `us` (state) - `someweirdstuff` (country), so it's perfectly valid case

Unless you missed something, the task is impossible in general. We know that `us` isn't a state, but regexp doesn't.

You can try to limit an amount of dashes in the city to one, or enumerate all possible countries, or do something like that... Anyway, this has nothing to do with regular expressions, really.

Comment: Its not impossible, but it is complex.

Comment: The general task without enumerating any known states/countries/etc. is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way. But, it would take a multi step process. In the first pass, replace all two letter states (since they are optional) with a different delimiter. In the second pass, replace all of the countries with a different delimiter so you can recognize cities. In the third pass, replace all city dashes with some other character and add back the states and countries with dash delimiters. In the final pass, replace your cities with a different delimiter with the delimiter you expect.

For instance:

1. replace /-(al|ca|az...)/ with ~$1   san-jose-ca-us = san-jose~ca-us
2. replace /-(.+)$/ with ~$1           san-jose~ca-us = san-jose~ca~us
3. replace /-/ with *$1                san-jose~ca~us = san*jose~ca~us
4. replace /~/ with -                  san*jose~ca~us = san*jose-ca-us

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to keep your information on 1 level hierarchy you can try the underscore delimiter. So, your url be like: `city_state_country`